# inverse ssh X forwarding

Tags: ssh

Suppose I've computers `office` and `home`. I want to connect from `home` to `office` through ssh and run a program from `home` that opens a window, let say `emacs`, on the `office` screen. Is it possible?

Comment: So are you asking if you can run X11 programs on `office`, when you start them on `office`, via an SSH session to office?  This is absolutely possible.

Comment: yes, connetting from `home`. But I want to show the program on the `office` monitor, not on `home` monitor

Comment: xauth gives me a headache, but check out this link.  http://zweije.home.xs4all.nl/xauth-7.html  If you find something useful here, repost what worked as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what permissions you have on the office machine and where you want the program to execute. If you're happy to have the program using the filesystem and CPU of the office machine then you can just execute a command with DISPLAY=:0, assuming that you have the relevant permissions (some distributions will require you to have a login at a the local machine before you can use the hardware on it).

If you want the program to run on home but display on office the best way would be to use SSH's reverse port forwarding feature. This will allow you to connect back from office to home via the initial SSH connection. You could forward the port for X, but I think there's more than one, and then you would need to set $DISPLAY manually, so I would recommend forwarding the SSH port.

See the -R option in the ssh manpage.

This should help:
http://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling

Example:
    user@home$ ssh -R 20000:localhost:22 office
    user@office$ ssh -p 20000 localhost

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible.
You need to enable X-Forwarding on ssh server (in your case home computer).

Follow this tutorial: http://maketecheasier.com/use-ssh-x-forwarding-to-run-remote-apps/2009/06/22

Comment: no, this is not what I'm asking. This is a normal X-forwarding from `office` to `home`, I want to do the reverse. I'm sittining on my `home` computer, and I want to open a window on my `office` computer, running a programin on 'office'

Comment: so you want to remotely issue commands on office computer? why not use any remote desktop or remote control utility for this purpose?

Comment: with a remote desktop I can visualize `office` desktop on `home` screen, this is not what I want